# SubscribeOptions for image_transport subscriber

Tags: ros, callbackqueue, image-transport

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like my image_transport subscriber to use a different callback queue than the global queue so that when ros::spingOnce() is called my image_transport callback is not triggered.

Normally I would create a new callback queue and pass that to the subscriber constructor via SubscribeOptions but image_transport doesn't seem to support that.

I am curious why image_transport does not support seperate callback queues and what I should do to separate my image_transport subscriber from ros::spinOnce()

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/263207/subscribeoptions-for-image_transport-subscriber/) by [holmes.kirby](https://answers.ros.org/users/20004/holmes.kirby/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2017-06-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-07**:
Could I ask you to post your approach / work-around as an answer and then accept your own answer? That way it's clearer that this question has been answered (instead of just closed).

Thanks.

**Comment by [holmes.kirby](https://answers.ros.org/users/20004/holmes.kirby/) on 2017-06-07**:
id be happy to but i need more reputation to reopen a closed question.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-07**:
I've re-opened it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Instead of separating the image_transport callback from the global callback queue, I have limited the global callback queue to the image_transport callback.

This isn't an elegant solution, i have to call callAvailable() which may not be clear to some other people who are less familiar to ros, but it does work.

I am still not sure why image_transport doesn't support the SubscribeOptions...

---

Originally posted by [holmes.kirby](https://answers.ros.org/users/20004/holmes.kirby/) with karma: 20 on 2017-06-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0